# Sending a Http Request from an Android Project (Java) using OkHttp

Tags: java, android, http, get, okhttp

I am just trying to send a simple **GET Request** from my **Android Project(JAVA)** to see if it connects to my app (**node/express.js**) using **OkHttp**

This is my **OkHttp** code  in  the **Main Activity**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request get = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://10.0.2.2:3000")
                .build();

client.newCall(get).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try{

                    ResponseBody responseBody=response.body();
                    Log.i("datadatadata", responseBody.string());
                    if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
});
```

If I set the url to **https:\google.com** the request goes through (So the **OkHttp** code is working fine).

So instead of **10.0.2.2:3000** I used my **IPv4 Address:3000** still doesnt work

Both of these addresses are accessible through the AVD browser(**10.0.2.2:3000** && **IPv4:3000**)

I know this is redundant but heres my **GET Route**

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log("called called")
    res.sendFile(index.html)
})
```

I have already added the **Internet Access Permision** in the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So I dont know what I am doing wrong with code could you guys please help me with this problem ??

**UPDATE**

Gave up on **OkHttp** was using this version

```
   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
```

Added **Volley** to my project

Added this in the manifest file

```
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Got the  Default Code From Android Site

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://10.0.2.2:3000";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        Log.i("response",response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("response error",error.getMessage())
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

This just works !!

I just checked that the **OkHttp** Library is at

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
```

I was probably getting an error because I was using an outdated version